# how to added placeholder for editable-select

Tags: angularjs

I need placeholder for editable-select in x-editable angularjs.

```
<span editable-select="data.CenterId" e-name="CenterId" e-form="rowform"  e-placeholder="Select Center"  e-ng-options="s.Id as s.Name for s in locationListData.centerData" onbeforesave="checkCenter($data)"  >
  {{ showCenter(data)}}
</span>
```

Comment: try  e-placeholder="place"

Comment: @ Sa E Chowdary ,i update my question,

Comment: dear not work @Sa E Chowdary

Comment: then check out this http://jsfiddle.net/nachoorme/RZK9u/1/ in this e-placeholder worked fine

Comment: dear it is working in editable-text .not working in editable-select...

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
<span editable-select="data.CenterId" e-name="CenterId" e-form="rowform"  e-ng-options="s.Id as s.Name for s in locationListData.centerData" onbeforesave="checkCenter($data)"  >
      {{ showCenter(data)|| 'Please Select Center' }}
    </span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/euzqyLp2/

Answer (score 0):

You just check [this](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/)

just try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/29/)..

You can do like `e-placeholder="Enter name"`

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <a href="#" editable-select="user.group" e-placeholder="Enter name" onshow="loadGroups()" e-ng-options="g.id as g.text for g in groups">
    {{ user.groupName || 'not set' }}
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: what? you mean ..you want placeholder in select fileld

Answer (score 0):

It's been two years since the original post, but since I had the same problem in 2018 (and many more, getting x-editable to work with BS-4) I thought I'd share my hacked solution: Add "prepend" to add a placeholder.

```
 $('.editable').editable({
mode: 'inline',
prepend: "Select",
url: selectedFeature.url,
params: function(params) {
  params = worker.processPUTdata(params);
  return params;
}
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/297

Add:

```
prepend: "Select something"
```

It works, but you have to process the data in javascript afterwords because x-editable assumes that "select" is a valid option.
Cheers.